# Tools to recover ASPX file from precompiled dll?

Tags: asp.net, decompiling

I have the compiled output from a site which uses asp precompilation.
The .aspx files are just a placeholder and there are .compiled files for each .aspx.

I'm trying to reconstruct a site's .aspx files from the precompiled assemblies.

I've looked in the compiled assemblies using reflector but reconstructing the .aspx looks like a bigger task than what I was hoping for. I  have a relatively short timeframe for this.Does anyone know of any easy way?
Are there any tools out there that can acheive this task?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to decompile the files. If the author didn't want to share it's source codes, you shouldn't steal it :-|

Comment: Well if you can read CLR, then `ILDASM` which is a part of Visual Studio.  If I am in the position of having to maintain a client's site where they no longer have the code, then that is usually the bottom line.

Comment: No not stealing it, the developer has left a client in the lurch with no source code... !

Answer (score 1):

Use .NET Reflector (free version available):  http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

With the FileDisassembler Addin:  http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/